# how to get the sum of duplicate values using VLookup

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a macro that will go through a worksheet, find a data item (this is present in multiple numbers) and get the sum of the number of counts against that value.

Example my sheet contains multiple tables with the headings : Fruit and number of Fruits

1st table:
          Apple     2
          Orange    3
          Mango     5

2nd table:
          Banana    6
          Apple     8
          Peach     1

3rd table:
          Orange    3
          Mango     1
          Apple     10

I need to parse through the sheet and get the sum of the number of apples.

Please help me if possible. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide a macro you are working at!

Comment: Use `=Sumifs()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use Excel bulit-in function `=SUMIF()`

=SUMIF(range_criteria; value_to_look_up; range_values)

**Example:** (According to your example worksheet)

To count all apples: `=SUMIF(A:A; "Apple"; B:B)` OR `=SUMIF(A:A; A1; B:B)`

**EDIT:**

There's also function called `=SUMIFS()` which works the same, but it's more recommended in the new Excels since 2007.

The only difference is in order of arguments and that you can put more than one condition to one formula: `=SUMIFS(range_values; range_criteria; value_to_lookup)`

**Example:**

`=SUMIFS(B:B; A:A; "Apple")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula, please look to the screenshot of it.

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(D15,$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(D15,$A$6:$B$8,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(D15,$A$11:$B$13,2,FALSE))
```

[image: Screenshot of the table]

Comment: You may want to check out the SUMIF formula.

Comment: Yes SJR, you are right, SUMIF formula is much easier than this.